# GCP endpoint integration with identity platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

would be grateful for directions. I'm a bit new to GCP. I want to secure the `Cloud Run`, which will be running some APIs. I was thinking of using the `Identity Platform` to create a set of users invoking the APIs with OAuth2.

The created are the `Cloud Run` service which is restricted from public access. As well the API endpoint which is currently publicly available and returns the response from the secured `Cloud Run` service. The `Identity Platform` with a test user is created as well and I can get the `SecureToken` back from the https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1.

The `API endpoint` config file is below:

```
  swagger: '2.0'
  host: *HOST*
  schemes:
    - https
  produces:
    - application/json
  x-google-backend:
    address: *https://HOST*
    protocol: h2
  paths:
    /hello:
      get:
        operationId: hello
        responses:
          '200':
            description: A successful response
            schema:
              type: string
        security:  #I presume I need to add security here
          - auth0_jwt: []
   #and here
   securityDefinitions:
     auth0_jwt:
       authorizationUrl: "" #???
       flow: "implicit"
       type: "oauth2"
       x-google-issuer: "https://securetoken.google.com/"  #???
       x-google-jwks_uri: ""   #???
       x-google-audiences: ""  #???
```

How would I add secure authentication from `Identity Platform` to `API Endpoint`?
I'm under the impression I need to update the config with security sections, but not sure what values to use. Or maybe that's not the way it is supposed to be done?

a post request to [https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[KEY]](https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=%5BKEY%5D), with `user:psw:returnSecureToken` returns me a token.

Comment: I've found a general introduction to Identity Platform here: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/concepts-authentication Can you provide more information on your idea about configuring with security sections?

Comment: the idea is to update the openApi config file with security definitions. I'm just not yet sure what to use for `issuer`, `jwks_uri`, etc.

Comment: I've found a link here: https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/google-cloud-endpoints Is this what you're after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just needed to update the API gateway config `yaml` with correct [security definitions](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users-firebase#configuring_your_openapi_document).

```
securityDefinitions:
    auth0_jwt:
        authorizationUrl: ""
        flow: "implicit"
        type: "oauth2"
        x-google-issuer: "https://securetoken.google.com/{google-project-ID}"
        x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com"
        x-google-audiences: "{google-project-ID}"
```